# Css elements dependent on screen size

Tags: css

I have had a problem with css for a couple of days and I found a temporary solution, however, I am not sure if it is good. I am writing a phone app and am using 'vh' and 'vw' as screen measurements (so the style is okay according to different screen sizes). The problem I am facing  comes when I click on an input and the keyboard pops up. Then the screen size decreases, and all the elements that I have with bottom: 10vh ( or any number of vh ), get pushed down, because the bottom decreases to the current screen size. I solved this by using px instead of vh, since it is independent of the screen size, but could cause problems (because users can use different screen sizes, so the style would look different on different phones). So both methods have cons. What is a good solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it isn't worthy to use 'vh' or 'vw'. as an example when you rotate your gadget also some styles get corrupted. when you use that take care of any size in width or height.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery method,

`$( window ).resize(function() {
  //function call which changes the sizes according to window.width() and window.height()
});`

It should do the job